# Никак не могу запустить программу - "Could not find or load main class"

Tags: java, javac

В общем учу Java`y и ещё ни разу не запускал через командную строку, ибо в начале были проблемы, оставил на потом. В итоге проблемы всплыли.

Прочитал практически всё по этой теме ( почему и т.д. ), но ничего не помогло, решив одну проблему выскакивает совершенно другая.

Пытаюсь запустить обычную программу, которую делал в самом начале, компилирует всё хорошо:

```
E:\projects\java.Adam2.0>cd E:\projects\java.Adam2.0\src\com\company\

E:\projects\java.Adam2.0\src\com\company>javac -cp . Q10.java
```

После, как и нужно, пытаюсь запустит:

```
E:\projects\java.Adam2.0\src\com\company>java -cp . Q10
Error: Could not find or load main class Q10
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/company/Q10 (wrong name: Q10)

E:\projects\java.Adam2.0\src\com\company>
```

Если что, то сам созданный класс у меня лежит в той же папке, где и сам java-файл, вот:

[image: ВОТ]

Возможно, я предполагаю, что в самом IntelliJ IDEA прописан путь где хранятся классы не правильно, но не знаю как это исправить.

Заранее спасибо за помощь)

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы запустить из командной строки, Вам надо перейти в каталог `E:\projects\java.Adam2.0\src>` и выполнить команду `java com.company.Q10` либо `java com\company\Q10`.

Пэкадж в классе не просто так указывается. Его надо учитывать при запуске.